# How use multiple conditions in xpath query?

Tags: php, xml, xpath

```
 $elements = $xpath->query(
   "//message[(@sender ='".$from." and @receiver = '".$username."') or
   (@receiver='unread' and @sender = '".$username."')]"
  );
```

Whats the problem with this code?
I need something like this `SELECT data WHERE ((sender == from AND receiver = username)OR(sender == username AND receiver = from))` from my xml file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`sprintf`](http://php.net/sprintf) instead. It's less messy and errors are more easy to spot.

```
$query = sprintf(
    '//message[
        (@sender = "%1$s" and @receiver = "%2$s") or
        (@receiver="unread" and @sender = "%2$s")
    ]',
    $from,
    $receiver
);
```

Also, make sure to sanitize `$from` and `$receiver` to prevent [XPath Injection attacks](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XPATH_Injection).

Answer (score 2):

You're missing a closing single quote after this portion:

```
(@sender ='".$from."
```

There's nothing wrong with your general approach.

Comment: thanks.. i wasted two hours by analyzing this error and failed to debug

Comment: @EbinPaulose - It's an easy mistake to make. It's a good idea to print out the constructed value early on (or use `sprintf` as others have suggested). It makes errors easier to spot.

Answer (score 1):

One of the problems with your code is that you're exposing yourself to injection attacks. Do you really trust $from and $username to be simple strings? Rather than building a query using string concatenation, it's much safer (and faster) to set up a parameterized query in which the parameters are supplied externally. I've no idea if the PHP API you are using allows you to do that.

Comment: unfortunately, none of the native XML APIs in PHP allow parameterized queries. There is a couple of 3rd party libs though, which compensate with their own implementations.